# Worst-case optimal Delaunay algorithm based on spatial sort and walking?

Tags: delaunay-triangulation, computational-geometry

Buchin [2] showed that under "reasonable" assumptions, (polynomial point spread) incremental construction of Delaunay triangulations using the biased randomized ordering of Amenta et al. [1] with a space filling curve takes $O(n \log n)$ even when points are located by walking from the last inserted point.  This reduces to $O(n)$ for uniformly random points if the BRIO jumps are treated carefully.

**Question**: Are there any "simple to compute" orders which are worst case $O(n \log n)$ for all general position inputs?  I am leaving "simple" intentionally vague, but roughly I mean simpler than computing the Delaunay triangulation itself (from which an optimal order is easy to derive).

1. [Amenta, Nina, Sunghee Choi, and Günter Rote. "Incremental Constructions con BRIO." (2003).](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/groups/ag-ti/teaching/WiSe2000/uploads/tx_tipublications/Incremental_constructions_con_BRIO_02.pdf)
2. [Buchin, Kevin. "Constructing Delaunay triangulations along space-filling curves." Algorithms-ESA 2009. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2009. 119-130.](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-04128-0_11)

Comment: Does the order in which points are inserted by Fortune's sweep-line algorithm qualify or not?

Comment: The sweep line insertion order is both as hard to compute as Delaunay and doesn't give $O(n \log n)$ since it jumps randomly around along the sweep line, so no.

Comment: Huh? Nothing happens "randomly" in Fortune's algorithm; it's deterministic.

Comment: Sorry, "wildly" is a better term than "randomly."  In any case, the distance through the triangulation between neighboring points would be $\sqrt{n}$ even for well distributed points, resulting in an $O(n^{1.5})$ algorithm.

Comment: I don't know a simple order theoretically, but there is an strategy that works very well in practice implemented in CGAL: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Spatial_sorting/index.html